# scipy genextreme fit returns different parameters from MATLAB gev fit function on the same data

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm trying to port some code from MATLAB to PYTHON and I realized `gevfit` function in MATLAB seems to behave differently from scipy `genextreme`, so I realized this minimal example:

MATLAB

```
% Create the MATLAB array
x = [0.5700, 0.8621, 0.9124, 0.6730, 0.5524, 0.7608, 0.2150, 0.5787, ...
           0.7210, 0.7826, 0.8181, 0.5449, 0.7501, 1.1301, 0.7784, 0.5378, ...
           0.9550, 0.9623, 0.6865, 0.6863, 0.6153, 0.4372, 0.5485, 0.6318, ...
           0.5501, 0.8333, 0.8044, 0.9111, 0.8560, 0.6178, 1.0688, 0.7535, ...
           0.7554, 0.7123, 0.7589, 0.8415, 0.7586, 0.3865, 0.3087, 0.7067];

disp(numbers);

parmHat = gevfit(x);

disp('Estimated parameters (A, B):');
disp(parmHat);
```

> Estimated parameters (A, B):    -0.3351    0.1962    0.6466

PYTHON

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

x = np.array([0.5700, 0.8621, 0.9124, 0.6730, 0.5524, 0.7608, 0.2150, 0.5787,
                    0.7210, 0.7826, 0.8181, 0.5449, 0.7501, 1.1301, 0.7784, 0.5378,
                    0.9550, 0.9623, 0.6865, 0.6863, 0.6153, 0.4372, 0.5485, 0.6318,
                    0.5501, 0.8333, 0.8044, 0.9111, 0.8560, 0.6178, 1.0688, 0.7535,
                    0.7554, 0.7123, 0.7589, 0.8415, 0.7586, 0.3865, 0.3087, 0.7067])

# Fit the GEV distribution to the data
parameters3 = stats.genextreme.fit(x)

print("Estimated GEV parameters:", parameters3)
```

> Estimated GEV parameters: (1.0872284332032054, 0.534605335200113,
> 0.6474387313912493)

I'd expect the same parameters, but results are totally different. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `genextreme.fit` is failing to compute the correct result.  You can help it generate the correct value by providing initial values for the numerical solver that are better than the default used by `genextreme.fit`. The initial values are set by providing values for the shape, location and scale parameters:

```
In [29]: from scipy.stats import genextreme

In [30]: x = np.array([0.5700, 0.8621, 0.9124, 0.6730, 0.5524, 0.7608, 0.2150, 0.5787,
    ...:                     0.7210, 0.7826, 0.8181, 0.5449, 0.7501, 1.1301, 0.7784, 0.5378,
    ...:                     0.9550, 0.9623, 0.6865, 0.6863, 0.6153, 0.4372, 0.5485, 0.6318,
    ...:                     0.5501, 0.8333, 0.8044, 0.9111, 0.8560, 0.6178, 1.0688, 0.7535,
    ...:                     0.7554, 0.7123, 0.7589, 0.8415, 0.7586, 0.3865, 0.3087, 0.7067])
    ...: 

In [31]: genextreme.fit(x, 0.34, loc=0.65, scale=0.20)  # Include initial guess of the parameters
Out[31]: (0.33513328610099824, 0.6466250071208526, 0.19615018966970216)
```

Note that the parameter `c` used by SciPy's `genextreme` is the negative of the parameter `k` in Matlab.  Also note that the order of the parameters in SciPy is *c*, *location*, *scale*, while in Matlab it is *k*, *scale*, *location*.

Comment: couple of questions.. how do you choose the initial values? Is there a way to have a behavior similar to MATLAB?